# Ambiguity in negation : Multasking is not productive and efficient

Tags: ambiguity

I didn't get any score from my English teacher as she said the following sentence on my answer sheet belongs to a partial negation.

> "Multasking is not productive and efficient."

By writing the above is it possible to mean:

> "Multasking is not productive and multasking is not efficient"

I want to know this sentence can have two meanings.
(Partial negation/Total denial)

Comment: Milk is not toxic and delicious.

Comment: @Jim: But ***Arsenic** is not toxic and delicious,* and ***Chocolate** is not toxic and delicious* are both syntactically "valid" utterances too. Though neither statement would be "true" if we parsed them the way we'd normally have expressed such things (using ***neither + nor*** rather than ***not + and***). Whether that's what he meant or not, we should understand OP's "partial negation" as meaning *one attribute applies, **but not both***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Exactly.  disambiguation of these types of imprecise statements is usually handled with context.

Comment: @Jim: I suggest it's normally handled by syntax/vocabulary *(neither+nor)*, but we can't ignore pragmatic context, so we know what OP probably means even if it's badly expressed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Fair enough.

Comment: @Jim: But I am intrigued. Would you personally be likely to use *not+and* in OP's context? I probably wouldn't, unless *productive and efficient* had been previously mentioned within the conversation (and I was thinking of it as a "single referent", which would certainly make a lot of sense if I mimed "air quotes" while uttering just those three words).

Comment: @FumbleFingers-  No. Personally I'd use *not... or*  in casual conversation or *neither ... nor* if I was writing.

Comment: ..   or if I *were* writing... :-)

Comment: Informal register: not x or y. More formal, neither x nor y. not x and y is ambiguous unless the the two elements are all but fused. I ate a sandwich, not bread and butter/cookies and milk/ham and eggs.

Comment: Did you mean 'multitasking'?

Comment: Any way you read it, that statement is wrong.

Comment: I would use "neither / nor," as in the answer given.  In terms of propositional logic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), "not X and Y" is correct. ("Not X or Y" would mean that one or the other *could* be true.) But it sounds simply awful in English.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could improve that sentence like this: "Multasking is neither productive nor efficient."